# Что означает @текст в комментариях php

Tags: php

Сразу извиняюсь за такой туповатый вопрос:
я знаю что @ типа отключает ошибки но часто встречаю в комментариях например типа

```
/ *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
```

подумал может они еще какие то функции выполняет?(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, википедия раскажет понятно: [phpDocumentator](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpDocumentor).

> Слова начинающиеся с символа «@» используются для написания команд парсера и называются дескрипторами (тегами, ярлыками). Стандартные дескрипторы стоят в начале строки.

Comment: аха, «@» используются для написания команд парсера и называются дескрипторами, все же не совсем понятно, их писать вообще имеет смысл в комментариях? 

P.S. Я пробовал удалить их, без проблем работает.

Comment: Лично я против вынесения функционала в комментарии, но есть библиотеки, которые требуют правильных тегов для работы.

- [Zend_XmlRpc_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.xmlrpc.server.html)
- [Doctrine Annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/ru/latest/reference/annotations.html)

и др.

Answer (score 4):

> P.S. Я пробовал удалить их, без
> проблем работает.

[@bemulima](/users/7998/bemulima) проблем и не будет в работе, потому что это комментарий! Такие комментарии пишутся для продакшна к примеру. Откройте тот же CodeIgniter и посмотрите как оформленны комментарии, сразу поймете зачем это сделано!